# How can Spring Cloud Dataflow Server use new tables( with custom prefix ) created for Spring batch and Spring cloud task?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have created spring cloud task tables i.e. `TASK_EXECUTION`, `TASK_TASK_BATCH` with prefix as `MYTASK_` and spring batch Tables with prefix `MYBATCH_` in oracle database.

There are default tables also there in the same schema which got created automatically or by other team mate.

I have bound my Oracle database service to `SCDF server` deployed on `PCF`.

How can i tell my Spring Cloud Dataflow server to use tables created with my prefix to render data on dataflow server dashboard?

Currently, SCDF dashboard uses tables with default prefix to render data. It works fine. I want to use my tables to render SCDF dashboard screens.

I am using `Dataflowserver version - 1.7.3` and Deployed it on `PCF` using `manifest.yml`

Answer (score 0):

There's an open story to add this enhancement via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#2048](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2048).

Feel free to consider contributing or share use-case details in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in a spring-cloud-dataflow and spring-cloud-skipper we use flyway to manage database schemas and it's not possible to prefix table names. Trying to support for this would add too much complexity and I'm not even sure if it'd be possible.