# Spring Cloud Data Flow - use tablePrefix for batch tables during bootstrap

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to bootstrap SCDF Schema and want to use a table prefix 'CUSTOM_' instead of BATCH_ for all batch tables.

tried using spring.cloud.task.table-prefix=CUSTOM_ and spring.batch.tablePrefix=CUSTOM_ but unable to create spring batch tables using prefix CUSTOM_.

Is table prefix supported by SCDF?

Comment: found this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589126/how-can-spring-cloud-dataflow-server-use-new-tables-with-custom-prefix-create

Comment: there seems to be an open item - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3461